# A story about a car chase in a traffic jam

Tags: identification-request

Quite some time ago (I can't really say for sure, but I think it was in the 90s) I've read a story about a car chasing in a traffic jam, and I can't figure out now what this story was, or in which book I read it.

It might have been a story by Stanislav Lem (an author I was reading a lot at that time), but I'm not sure.

It was, as far as I remember, a short story (contained in a paperback book with several stories). I read it in German, but it might have been a translation. The protagonist was the one chased, and as far as I remember, the story was written in first-person present tense.

The story was basically the thoughts of the protagonist, on how to escape. He's on the middle lane, and considers that to get off the road, he would first need to get to the left or right lane, but for some reason that I don't remember, it would give him a disadvantage to do so.

At the end of the story, he considers why he is chased after all, and

> comes to the conclusion that he is chased to prevent him from killing the driver of the car in front of him. So he shoots the driver of that car, and thus ends the chase by it becoming pointless. Indeed, if I remember correctly, he contemplates a full sequence of killers in that traffic jam, each of them intending to kill the one in front to prevent that one from killing the one in front of him.